# Error <generator object get_average_rating.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000000000156F728>

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to print result of this

```
average1 = 3.82 
average2 = 3.98 

short_rating1 = [3.5, 4.5, 4.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 3.5, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 4.5, 4.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0] 
short_rating2 = [3.5, 4.5, 5.0, 4.5, 5.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.0, 3.5, 3.0, 5.0, 4.0, 4.5, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.5, 3.0] 

denominator = (math.sqrt(sum((a - average1) ** 2)) * math.sqrt(sum(((b - average2) ** 2))) for a, b in zip(short_rating1, short_rating2))

print(denominator)
```

Comment: you wrapped the function in parenths which yields a generator

Comment: That's not an error; it's doing exactly what you asked. It's printing the value of `denominator`, which is a `generator` object. You want the list of values that the generator produces; `values = list(denominator)`.

Comment: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @sayaton Your code leaves at least 4 values undefined; it's impossible for us to say what this code is doing without a complete example.

Comment: average1 = 3.82
average2 = 3.98

short_rating1 = [3.5, 4.5, 4.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 3.5, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 4.5, 4.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
short_rating2 = [3.5, 4.5, 5.0, 4.5, 5.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.0, 3.5, 3.0, 5.0, 4.0, 4.5, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.5, 3.0]

Answer (score 0):

`sum((a - average1) ** 2)` and `sum(((b - average2) ** 2))` are your problem.  `sum` is a function that takes an iterable and sums its elements.  `(a - average1) ** 2` is a float, so you get an error.  Removing the `sum` calls gives

```
denominator = (math.sqrt((a - average1) ** 2) * math.sqrt((b - average2) ** 2) for a, b in zip(short_rating1, short_rating2))
list(denominator)
# [0.15359999999999993, 0.3536000000000001, 0.18360000000000018, 0.1663999999999999, 0.18360000000000018, 0.3264000000000001, 0.006400000000000003, 0.09360000000000009, 0.8735999999999999, 0.09360000000000009, 0.8035999999999999, 0.5664, 0.6664000000000001, 0.6936000000000002, 0.016400000000000012, 0.1663999999999999, 0.0036000000000000064, 0.013600000000000015, 1.7835999999999999, 0.5664, 0.016400000000000012, 0.0036000000000000064, 0.016400000000000012, 0.09360000000000009, 1.1564]
```